# Removing Characters With Regular Expression in List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list-comprehension

I am learning python and I am trying to do some text preprocessing and I have been reading and borrowing ideas from Stackoverflow. I was able to come up with the following formulations below, but they don't appear to do what I was expecting, and they don't throw any errors either, so I'm stumped.

First, in a Pandas dataframe column, I am trying to remove the third consecutive character in a word; it's kind of like running a spell check on words that are supposed to have two consecutive characters instead of three

```
buttter = butter
bettter = better
ladder = ladder
```

The code I used is below:

```
import re
docs['Comments'] = [c for c in docs['Comments'] if re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1', c)]
```

In the second instance, I just want to to replace multiple punctuations with the last one.

```
????? = ?
..... = .
!!!!! = !
----  = -
***** = *
```

And the code I have for that is:

```
docs['Comments'] = [i for i in docs['Comments'] if re.sub(r'[\?\.\!\*]+(?=[\?\.\!\*])', '', i)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use

```
docs['Comments'] = docs['Comments'].str.replace(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', regex=True)
    .str.replace(r'([^\w\s]|_)(\1)+', r'\2', regex=True)
```

The `r'(\w)\1{2,}'` regex finds three or more repeated word chars and `\1\1` replaces with two their occurrences. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F5Hx90/1).

The `r'([^\w\s]|_)(\1)+'` regex matches repeated punctuation chars and captures the last into Group 2, so `\2` replaces the match with the last punctuation char. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F5Hx90/2).